# Best practice for unit conversion between imperial and metric

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have an app I'd like to open up to an international audience & so I need to accept different units, to keep it simple let's say miles & kilometers.

I figured I've got 3 options:

- Use Meteor's `transform` option on my collection
- Use Simple Schema's `autoValue`
- Manually adjust the value every time I send/receive it from the DOM
- Store mi/km in different fields (take advantage of that NoSQL!)
- ?

What is the pattern you've found most useful? Any examples would be great.

Answer (score 1):

For smaller units of measure like yards and meters, I would use an integer of centimeters. It can be converted to any unit larger than itself easily and you shouldn't have any issues with floats. On a scale of miles and kilometers, I'd store integers of meters.

As far as how to transform them back and forth, I'd keep that in the view, not the model. I'm not a meteor guy so I'm not sure how that translates, but I'm saying I'd use javascript to either multiply meters by 1000 for kilometers or by 1609 for miles. There's even Javascript libraries to assist in this kind of internationalization.